# Leap motion and Integration Tests

Tags: testing, unity-game-engine, integration-testing, leap-motion, unity-test-tools

I am currently using Leap Motion alongside Unity3D in a VR-project I am making. 
I finished my unit tests finding inspiration from this site https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/03/unit-testing-part-2-unit-testing-monobehaviours/. Now I need to make some integration tests to e.g. ensure that a Leap Motion hand pressing one of my UI buttons in Unity executes succsesfully.

I am using the UnityTestTools and have tried to explore the features presented to me, but the main problem I am seeing is that in order to use the Integration Test Tool you have to "drag" your Game Objects into the test scene. This is although not possible with the Leap Motion, due to the Game Objects being create when the hands enter the scene.

I was thinking the best way to get around this was to just trigger the onClick event on the Leap UI button, but I fail to find a way to do this in Unity Test Tools which leads me to the overall question:

**What are the general approach to integration testing when using Leap Motion?**

I would love some input on this matter.